# Why isn't the "this." command needed in this constructor? (java)

Tags: java, constructor, class

I'm reading a book about java. It just got to explaining how you create a class called "deck" which contains an array of cards as its instance variable(s). Here is the code snippit:

```
class Deck { 
    Card[] cards; 
    public Deck (int n) { 
        cards = new Card[n]; 
    } 
}
```

why isn't the `this.` command used?

for example why isn't the code this:

```
class Deck { 
    Card[] cards; 
    public Deck (int n) { 
       this.cards = new Card[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an error in the second example. There are 2 `[`.

Comment: Note: If you want to discuss whether it's a *good idea* to either use or omit the `this.`, then there are plenty of other places to debate that.  For example, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132777/do-you-prefix-your-instance-variable-with-this-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this.` is implicit.

In general, it's a best practice (at least *I* consider it one) to only use `this` when absolutely necessary. When you have a local variable named `cards` and a member variable named `cards`, for example, you'll need `this.cards` to refer to the member variable, as `cards` refers to the local variable.

In such a case, `this` is a good idea (although it might be a better idea to rename the member variable).

In every other case, where an implicit `this` can work, use it.

Comment: can this. always be omitted then? 
or do you mean that the author intends it to be there but isn't writing it because its implicit relative to the reader?

Comment: @David: It can always be omitted unless you also have a local variable with the same name (as then `cards` on its own would be the local variable not the instance variable, and you'd need `this.cards` to explicitly reference the instance).

Comment: why should one only use this when absolutely necessary?

Comment: Because it's implicit and everyone should know that? It's also extraneous; 5 extra characters that do not help readability in the slightest. Well, *I* consider it thus... obviously that's subjective.

Answer (score 20):

Because there is no ambiguity. There is only one `cards` variable. `this` would be needed if there were two - one of which being an instance variable (part of the class, as it currently is), and the other - an argument of the constructor.

And btw, `this` isn't a "command". It's a "keyword".

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to qualify all access to members with the `this` keyword. You only need to use it whenever another variable is hiding the member method.

And that is not a feature limited to the constructor, but available in all methods:

```
public class Test 
{
   private int member;
   private int value;
   public Test(int value) {
      member = 5;
      this.value = value; // required to differentiate from the parameter
   }
   public void f( int member ) {
      int value = 5
      this.member = value; // assign local 'value' (5) to member 'member'
      this.value = member; // assign parameter 'member' to member 'value'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The object's `this` reference is implied, but it can be useful for clarity (and it's necessary for disambiguation between an object's member and a local variable of the same name, as in the constructor below):

```
   public class Foo {
       final private int x;

       public Foo(int x) { this.x = x; }

       public int getX() { return this.x; }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the identifier `cards` in the constructor, the compiler notices that the field (a.k.a. member variable) `cards` is in scope, and uses it.  `this.cards` would only be necessary to resolve ambiguities, for instance if you also had a local variable or parameter named `cards`.

Answer (score 3):

It would have sense if you also have a parameter named `cards`. Then `this.cards` would specify that you mean exactly field `cards` of class, not the parameter.

But anyway it's counted a good practice to use `this.` in cases as described in your example.

Comment: No, it’s not good practice to add visual noise to your source code.

Comment: @Bombe: That depends on who you ask.  *Some* people consider using `this.` to be good practice, while others don't.

Comment: Indeed. So, it’s not a good practice because there are no good practices, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

`This` is implied.

Let's elaborate:

```
class Deck { 
     Card[] cards; 
     public Deck (Card[] cards) { 
          this.cards = cards; 
     } 
}
```

In this case you pass in an array of cards that shares the same name as the object's array of cards.  `This` refers to your object's datamember, not the constructor's parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The "this" keyword is redundant in that case. cards is already defined at class scope and the complier knows that the member is part of "this" class.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is implied. There is no need to use "this". I usually put it there just to make the code readable, but again it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

I try to select variable names in a way that doesn't require the "this" keyword.  That is, if I have a property named "value", I will pass to a parameter called val.

A good use of the "this" keyword is for constructor overloading.  Consider the following (I will use this. to demonstrate the difference):

```
public class Person
{
   int age;
   public Person(int age)
   {
      this.age=age;
   }
   public Person()
   {
      this(25); //default age
   }
}
```

When at all possible, I will try to avoid having the property and parameter name the same to avoid what you see on line 6.  However, the use of the this keyword for calling another constructor is a good way to prevent code duplication.  This is a trivial example, but when you start finding yourself with constructors that do a lot of the same work with small differences between them, it comes in quite handy.